# R: Loop a sequence and throw it in separate lists

Tags: r, list, loops, date

I try to get a list consisting of 17 components. Every single list should contain a vector of 12 dates beginning with 2003-06-01. 
Manually, it would look like this:

```
wholedate <- seq(as.Date("2003-06-01"), as.Date("2020-05-01"), by="months")
date <- list()
date[[1]] <- wholedate[1:12]
date[[2]] <- wholedate[13:24]
...
date[[17]] <- wholedate[193:204]
```

I've tried it with the following loop, unfortunately it just creates 17 lists with the last 12 months (from 2019-06-01 to 2020-05-01).

```
date <- list()
wholedate <- seq(as.Date("2003-06-01"), as.Date("2020-05-01"), by="months")
for(i in 1:17) {
  for(j in seq(1,193,by=12)) {
    for(k in seq(12,204,by=12)) {
      date[[i]] <- wholedate[j:k]
    }}}
```

I hope that somebody could help me out on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you are nesting the loops when in fact elements j and k of their respective loops should go hand in hand. I find this easiest using the `purrr` package. Note that you don't need to start with an empty list when running this:

```
date <- map2(seq(1, 193, by = 12), seq(12, 204, by = 12), ~ wholedate[.x:.y])
date

[[1]]
 [1] "2003-06-01" "2003-07-01" "2003-08-01" "2003-09-01" "2003-10-01" "2003-11-01" "2003-12-01" "2004-01-01" "2004-02-01" "2004-03-01"
[11] "2004-04-01" "2004-05-01"

[[2]]
 [1] "2004-06-01" "2004-07-01" "2004-08-01" "2004-09-01" "2004-10-01" "2004-11-01" "2004-12-01" "2005-01-01" "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01"
[11] "2005-04-01" "2005-05-01"

#cut for brevity

[[16]]
 [1] "2018-06-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01" "2018-11-01" "2018-12-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01"
[11] "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"

[[17]]
 [1] "2019-06-01" "2019-07-01" "2019-08-01" "2019-09-01" "2019-10-01" "2019-11-01" "2019-12-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01"
[11] "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01"
```